# Making bus routes in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, route

I am a novice.

Aim is to make bus routes in ArcGIS Network Analyst, so specifying two points on the map, I could see what buses to ride with minimal layovers and time.

Please tell me where it is written in detail.

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS Network Analyst provides network-based spatial analysis, such as routing, fleet routing, travel directions, closest facility, service area, and location-allocation. Using ArcGIS Network Analyst, you can dynamically model realistic network conditions, including one-way streets, turn and height restrictions, speed limits, and variable travel speeds based on traffic. You can easily build networks from your GIS data by using a sophisticated network data model.

The General Transit Feed Specification (GTFS) is a recently-developed data format for storing public transit routes, stops, and schedules.  GTFS data is used in Google Maps transit trip planning. Many major public transit systems have made up-to-date GTFS data for their systems readily available for download.
Add GTFS to a Network Dataset allows you to add GTFS data to an ArcGIS network dataset so you can run schedule-aware analyses using the Network Analyst tools.

1. [How to use](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/networkanalyst/usage)
2. [Sample from blog for using General Transit Feed Specification (GTFS)](http://www.transit.melindamorang.com/)
3. [Network Analyst brochures](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-networkanalyst.pdf)
4. [Routing video demo](http://vid01.esri.com/winmmedia/na/naroutes.wmv)